# Doxygen: parameters of member my_function are not (all) documented

Tags: c, doxygen

I have this `C` file:

```
/**
 * Blah blah blah.
 *
 * @file   myfile.c
 * @author Carlos Alexandro Becker (author@mail.com)
 *
 * @brief  Some Brief.
 */
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myfile.h"

/**
 * Blah blah blah.
 * @param obj The obj
 * @return True
 */
static bool
something_has_blah (jobject * obj)
{
  return true;
}

void
my_fn (JNIEnv * env, jobject * obj, int number)
{
   // code
}
```

And the `.h` file:

```
/**
 * Blah blah blah.
 *
 * @file   myfile.h
 * @author Carlos Alexandro Becker (author@mail.com)
 *
 * @brief  Some Brief.
 */
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_BIND_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_BIND_INCLUDED

/**
 * Blah blah blah
 * @param env Java Environment
 * @param obj Obj
 * @param number Number
 */
void my_fn (JNIEnv * env, jobject * obj, int number);

#endif
```

For some reason, Doxygen is complaining about this function:

```
error: parameters of member my_fn are not (all) documented (warning treated as error, aborting now)
```

The Doxyfile looks like:

```
WARN_AS_ERROR         = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED  = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR     = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC      = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF     = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES
GENERATE_HTML         = NO
GENERATE_LATEX        = NO
```

What am I missing in the documentation of that method to make Doxygen happy?
I tried to add a `@return void` and other stuff but nothing worked out.

By the way, here is the full reproducible code: https://github.com/caarlos0/happy-doxygen

Comment: Huh. I wonder why it says "member".

Comment: @melpomene yeah, I'm new to doxygen, so I have no idea either...

Comment: @melpomene I also added the `.h` file, I guess the `member` thing is because of that.

Comment: You shouldn't do this documentation in both header and implementation files. Try removing it from your .c file.

Comment: @Saraph I added it in the C file trying to fix the issue, it doesn't work either way..

Comment: I get the impression that the problem arises from the fact that you didn't select any output format.

Comment: @albert what a long shot, right in the bullseye.. it was it... is it a bug?

Comment: @albert would you like to answer with your solution so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @altert said in comments, the problem is the lack of output format.

Changed the lines

```
GENERATE_HTML         = NO
GENERATE_LATEX        = NO
```

to

```
GENERATE_HTML         = YES
GENERATE_LATEX        = YES
```

For some reason fixed the problem.